# In Windows, is there any software to prevent duplication of files in a folder?

Tags: windows, software-rec, deduplication

Let's say I have two files `c:\f1\data.txt` and `c:\f2\data.txt`.

If I issue the command

`copy c:\f2\data.txt c:\f1\data\`

I will receive a warning about the potential overwriting. I will receive the same warning, as a dialog box, if I try to graphically drag `data.txt` from `c:\f2\` and  drop it in `c:\f1`. This behavior is due to the fact that the files have the same name (`data.txt`). I am happy with this behavior but I would like to extend it also to files *with different names but with the same contents*.

Let's say I have two files `c:\f1\foo.txt` and `c:\f2\bar.txt` and let's say `foo.txt` contains one line `Hello World!` and `bar.txt` contains one line `Hello World!`, so `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` have the same content, now the command

`copy c:\f2\bar.txt c:\f1\`

will succeed, but I would like it to fail.

I would be happy to have this behavior just for one folder, is there any software to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

There are no programs that I can think of that do this.

You can easily write a script or application to do a compare before a copy and warn you if they are identical.  *However*... there is always a caveat.  How do you do the compare?  Since you are dealing with text files, data might *appear* to be the same, however it isnt.  Take the following examples:

> This is a test.

and

> This is a test.

The lines look exactly the same.  However, to a computer they are different.  Take your mouse, left click and hold, and highlight the first example.  Then highlight the second line.  See the difference?  There is a space after the period of the second example.  These strings, while conveying the same information, are not identical.  Even a difference of a single character, 1 byte, would allow the copy.  If you are OK with that, then the application or script is super easy.  I would recommend just getting the hash values of the two files and comparing that value.  If the values are the same, warn and deny the copy.

Answer (score 0):

[UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare.html) can do what you want if you define some sync rules as you can see [here](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultracompare/sync-folders.html).

Comment: Does UltraCompare *prevent* me to make file duplication? It seems to me it just works *later* when I already had duplications...